# How to run JAVA 8 function in Openshift

Tags: java, jsp, openshift

I have used the AES algorithm to encrypt and decrypt the password using Java in web application and have deployed that application in Openshift server. But it not functioning as expected. I am assuming that AES uses java 8 version thats' why it is not functioning correctly. So any one can let me know please what I do so that same AES examples work in Openshift.
I have used the AES example like this:
http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html

Comment: How is it not functioning correctly?

Comment: I am using this (import java.util.Base64;) and if I uses hdk 1.7 it is not working but on jdk 1.8 it is working fine. So I think Openshift using 1.7

Comment: The example you reference actually uses java 1.6 so you should have no problem running it on java 1.7. 
java.util.Base64 is a java 1.8 new feature. Try sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and Decoder instead. Or switch to org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to run Java 8 in Openshift, one option is to create an app with DIY cartridge

First you connect via ssh using the rhc command line tool

```
rhc ssh -a <appname>
```

Then download and unzip the Java 8 JDK in the Data directory (code for Java 8 JDK update 40)

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
wget -c -O "jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz" --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u40-b25/jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz"
tar xzf jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
rm -f jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

then edit the start action hook to point the env vars JAVA_HOME and PATH to the downloaded JDK

```
JAVA_HOME=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_40
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

**Update**: Another option

At the time of the writting, i'm not sure if the Wildfly cartridges were there already, but creating an application with Wildfly, have Java 8 enabled by default too, as well as support for JavaEE 7.

Just keep in mind that with the basic gear, which have a limit of 250 threads, the default config of wildfly is a bit liberal and sometimes reaches that cap, and starts throwing exceptions, but it is possible to modify the configuration to tune it down.

Also the JBossEAP cartridge allows Java8 in combination with JavaEE 6, but comes with Java7 enabled by default. In order to change to Java 8 you need to modify the cartridge markers, disabling Java 7 and enabling Java 8.